# Is it a good practice to use git merge `ours` strategy in a git flow release process

Tags: git, git-flow

I've 3 branches: `Dev` (on which developers push their code), `Qa` (on which tests are done) and `Master` (production code).

When releasing, we `merge` (default merge) `Qa` into `Master` and `Dev` into `Qa`. I've also found people using `rebase` instead of `merge`.

But, what about using `merge -s ours` ?

This will ensure that the code of `Master` is exactly the one of `Qa` we just tested. We get rid of side effects of the default `merge` (like kept code of `Master` against `Qa` which shouldn't). Moreover, the automation tool can do the whole release for us because we don't get any merge conflict during the process.

Is it a good idea ? And what's the best practice ?

Comment: If you merge Qa into Master using `merge -s ours` you will get _no_ effects from Qa at all. Master will be completely unchanged. Is that really what you want? And if it is, what is the point of the merge in the first place?

Comment: I see some close votes saying this is opinion based. This is NOT an opinion based question. The answer is absolutely No, you should pretty much *never* use `-s ours` in Git Flow when merging a release branch into `master`.

Comment: I'm curious what gave you the idea to use `-s ours` in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve? In Git Flow release branches should always be *able to be* a fast-forward merge into `master`. (But it is recommended to use `--no-ff` in Git Flow.)

Comment: I wonder if you meant to ask about `-X ours` instead of `-s ours`? I'd still say that's a bad idea, but at least it would make a little bit more sense, in the context of resolving conflicts.

Comment: @TTT: "best practices" questions are by definition off topic, but correctness ones aren't, so if this is just plain wrong, then yeah, it's not off topic. :-)

Comment: @torek agreed! I suppose it's sort of a downer when your question would have been off topic but the suggestion is so bad that it becomes on topic. At least knowledge is gained though. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good idea?

Hm, I doubt it. `git merge -s ours` pretends to do a merge where in fact it rather does a `reset`. You effectively ignore all commits that were made to `master`. And that is the point I would rather investigate:

How can it be that there needs to be a (non-fast-forwarding) merge on `master`? If the only way `master` ever advances is by merging from `QA` or making a commit that is immediatly merged back into `QA` then there can not be any conflicts (unless the history of `QA` was rewritten). If on the other hand there are some commits to `master` that were not merged back to `QA` it is probably not a good idea to just discard them, which you would do using `git merge -s ours`.

Edit: Mention the possibility of hotfixes to `master`

Comment: In Git Flow, `master` can get ahead of `release` when there's a `hotfix` merged into `master`, but Git Flow requires merging that hotfix (or `master`) back into `release` at the same time. Therefore I agree, `release` branches should always (be able to) be fast-forwarded into `master`.

Comment: @TTT Thanks for reminding me of the possibility of hotfixes. I rephrased my answer to explicitly mention them.

Comment: Good edit. But now I just realized something else- which direction is the merge going? If `QA` is getting merged into `master`, then you would have `master` checked out and `git merge QA -s ours` would ignore all changes on `QA`, making the merge pointless. (You're mentioning ignoring commits on `master` though.)

Comment: @TTT Since there is no strategy "theirs" I guess the OP wants to basically merge `master` into `QA` and then reset `master` to the new HEAD.

Comment: Thanks all for your help! The point I've missed was "you should always be able to do a fast-forward merge". If I get a merge conflict, I would like to know it because it means something goes wrong. That's why I should not use the `ours` strategy, you're right!